# What methods are used to deal with sophists?

Tags: sophism

Time and time again, I hear of "clever phrases" to try to get away with something:

1. The software engineer totally messed up on a 5 month project, and his contractor agency just said it as "he obviously dropped the ball this time, but he deservers another chance", making software engineering that span 5 months sound like a volleyball game where people are **supposed** to be dropping the ball sometimes.
2. A guy who did the work which, say, deserves a score of 25 out of 100, which is a rock bottom, poor quality work.  His boss just defend him as "he didn't do the **most perfect** job", and tried to get away with it, as an 80 point job also classify as "not the most perfect" and he just mixed a 25 point together with an 80 point job in the same class.
3. A guy made multiple women pregnant and ghost the women, and when the women openly said something, the guy said, "we don't show the dirty laundry out in the public".  While it is true we don't show dirty laundry out in public, the dirty laundry has no moral implication, but making multiple women pregnant and ghost them, clearly is a different thing.
4. A person made some arrangement with the house owner management company manager due to the home owner association went extravagant to replace all windows and sliding windows and all sidings of the houses and while they are at it, they may as well replace 10-year old roofs prematurely, and all owner needed to come up with US$90,000.  Later on, the board of Home Owner Association sent him to collection and the firm brought up all unreasonable fees such as "pre-lien assessment fees" and it totaled US$1000.  The person contacted the board saying there was a prior arrangement made with the manager and so they shouldn't send him to collection. The board lady said that manager went onto a surgery and then left the company and they didn't see anything in the file folder.  The person said if you look for it in my folder or ask the manager if that really happen, you can find out it is true.  The board lady said, "I am not going to do that. It is water under the bridge."  So water under the bridge is down there and *gone*, but in this case the person made the arrangement with the manager and if verified, they really shouldn't send him to collection, but she just refused to check and call it water under the bridge.

By what methods do people deal with sophists?  Or is it no method because they just deny whatever and only what the "power" is can deal with it, be it the law or the godfather if the culture is so.

Comment: The first two are just business-speak. You never make waves, you never make sharp statements, you just la-di-da everything. The words sound vaguely like English but they're not English. It's corporate English, an entirely different dialect, in which meaning is absent.

Comment: I don’t see any sophistry here.

Comment: The answer is deductive reasoning! Sophistry was likely what motivated Aristotle to create the syllogism. The syllogism is deliberately made to eliminate emotive words or Rhetoric from the reasoning process. All deception involves someone OMITTING relevant information that could change the answer or conclusion. This is why most people disrespect Philosophy as a discipline. There are too many that think we all are philosophers or philosophy is just about thinking. Also people constantly  bring up people don't speak in  syllogisms in reality. That is the point: write this way to reduce deception